# Android Camera Hardware zoom

Tags: android, zooming

we are developing an Android App to be used on 1 of 2 Android cameras. Specifically the Nikon S800C.

We are able to use digital zoom but as yet we have not found a way of handling the hardware zoom which is the whole point of using a camera rather than a basic smart phone.

We cannot use the internal camera app as we have to make a custom camera overlay and preview screen. As such we have had to compose our own camera app.

It seems from what I have been advised it is not technically possible to control the camera hardware zoom from within our own app.

So my question is: Is this really the case? Is there absolutely no way of building a custom camera app that has a custom camera capture experience and also a camera HARDWARE zoom?

If this is the case, is there a way of creating a custom preview and camera overlay screen for the existing internal camera app on our device? Which would negate the need to build our own.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question so far?